# Displaying backend database data in angular2 table

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Hi I'm having an issue while trying to display the data received from my API call into an HTML table using angular2.

I am trying to display the name of each group I receive from backend in a table.

From console log, I can see that my data is in the following format:

```
{
    "list":[
        {"group_uuid":"26750058-eda0-448b-a4ff-bedf5f7c70e1","name":"Group 2","description":null}, 
        {"group_uuid":"2f95cebc-7cc2-4c31-bc05-75890e8fee35","name":"group 6","description":null},
        {"group_uuid":"3eb5a9f6-4ad7-4757-a0f7- f533bbcbcece","name":"Group1","description":null}
    ]
}
```

Based off of other answers, I have tried this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of grouplist.list">  
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

^ The above says 'List not found' as an error.

If I try:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of grouplist">  
   <td>{{item}}</td>
</tr>
```

It prints the raw JSON data in the table once and that is all (looks the same as console log).

Any suggestions?

Comment: `raw json data` If it's in JSON format, then it's a string, not an object, which is a problem...

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the `string` to an `Object`. For that, use `JSON.parse()`

I leave the [working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zakkx8)